# Написание слов "государственный" и "федеральный" в названии организации

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, деловой-язык

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в названии организаций с прописной или строчной буквы надо писать слова "государственный" и "федеральный"?
Например, государственное образовательное учреждение высшего образования...

Answer (score 1):

Писать надо так, как зарегистрировано в уставных документах. Приходится констатировать, что там - полный разброд и шатания. Как хотят, так и пишут.

Если же говорить о правилах русского языка, то причин для написания "государственного" и "федерального" с заглавной нет никаких. Если только этот не первое слово в названии. В вашем примере, если он начинается с государственного, то ***"Государственное образовательное учреждение высшего образования..."***

Answer (score 1):

**Примеры официальных названий:**

Государственное образовательное учреждение высшего профессионального образования «Первый Санкт-Петербургский государственный медицинский университет имени академика И.П. Павлова».

Государственное бюджетное общеобразовательное учреждение города Москвы "Лицей № 1580 при МГТУ имени Н.Э.Баумана".

В официальных названиях учебных заведений, фирм, предприятий  используется **совмещенная форма записи**: имя собственное строится по обычному правилу (с прописной буквы пишется первое слово и входящие имена собственные), но при этом включает  **второе название, заключенное в кавычки**.  Кавычки обозначают **границу между двумя  наименованиями** предприятия (по виду собственности  и по роду деятельности).